# Alt-codes only work in Java string when run within Netbeans

Tags: java, csv, netbeans, unicode

I have a small java program that reads a given file with data and converts it to a csv file.

I've been trying to use the arrow symbols: ↑, ↓, → and ← (Alt+24 to 27) but unless the program is run from within Netbeans (Using F6), they will always come out as '?' in the resulting csv file.

I have tried using the unicodes, eg "\u2190" but it makes no difference.

Anyone know why this is happening?

As requested, here is a sample code that gives the same issue. This wont work when run using the .jar file, just creating a csv file containing '?', however running from within Netbeans works.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class Sample {

String fileOutName = "testresult.csv";

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Sample test = new Sample();
    test.saveTheArrow();

}

public void saveTheArrow() {
    try (PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileOutName)) {
            outputStream.print("←");
            outputStream.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Probably an encoding issue, but without seeing the code it's going to be difficult to help... Please see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @assylias I've added a sample that recreates the issue.

Comment: What version of Java do you use?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean but Netbeans is using jdk1.8.0_74

Comment: `new PrintWriter(string)` uses the default charset, which may be different in Netbeans and the console. Have you tried specifying a charset, for example: `Files.write(Paths.get("testresult.csv"), "←".getBytes(UTF_8));`? Also how do you open the csv? (on Window, it opens ok with Notepad but not with Wordpad for example).

Comment: I open the .csv file with Notepad++ to check its accurate then its imported to a google sheet. Not sure how to specify a charset..

Comment: Yep, that works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new PrintWriter(fileOutName)` uses the default charset of the JVM - you may have different defaults in Netbeans and in the console.

Google Sheet uses UTF_8 according to [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/jtJHcLwAICM) so it would make sense to save your file using that character set:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("testresult.csv"), "←".getBytes(UTF_8));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the "<-" character in your editor is for sure not the desired byte 0x27.

Use

```
outputStream.print( new String( new byte[] { 0x27}, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```